# MissingMethodException, InvalidOperationException when mocking COM Interop interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, com-interop

I'm trying to unit test a class which takes a dependency of an interface from a COM interop library.

The method under test:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IRequestProcessor5 processor)
{
    processor.AuthPreferences.PutIsReadOnly(false);
    // more configuration statements...
}
```

I really want to use recursive mocks here, since I have no control over the shape of the COM code. My first attempt:

```
[Fact]
public void ConfigureAuth_SetsReadOnlyToFalse()
{
    var mockProcessor = new Mock<IRequestProcessor5>{DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock};
    _testSubject.ConfigureAuth(mockProcessor.Object);
    mockProcessor.Verify(p => p.AuthPreferences.PutIsReadOnly(false));
}
```

This throws the following exception (from the Verify call in the test):

> System.InvalidOperationException
>   variable 'p' of type 'QBXMLRP2Lib.RequestProcessor3' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined.

My initial assumption was that the recursive mocking is working but something bizarre was happening in the `Verify` expression, so I tried commenting out the `Verify` to test that assumption. That then throws the following exception (from the method under test):

> System.MissingMethodException
>   Error: Missing method 'instance class QBXMLRP2Lib.IAuthPreferences [MyProject] QBXMLRP2Lib.IRequestProcessor5::get_AuthPreferences()' from class 'Castle.Proxies.IRequestProcessor5Proxy'.

So the recursive mocking appears to *not* be working. Also, even with the mocks in `Loose` mode, the `MissingMethodException` gets thrown unless a `Setup()` is provided.

What's going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: The "embed interop types" feature only embeds the types and interface methods (!) that your program is actually using.  This is not necessarily compatible with a mock that tries to cover all methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, in Solution Explorer select the COM interop reference from the unit tests project. In Properties, change `Embed Interop Types` to False. Moq will now behave as expected for the COM interfaces.

I don't actually understand exactly *what* is happening here. Weird and eccentric behaviour is kind of normal at the intersection of Deep Magic (COM Interop) and Deep Magic (the Expressions-and-DynamicProxies core of Moq). However, I have confirmed the fix does work.